# Matrix Exponential of a Singular Matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, exponential-function

I ran into a difficult question today as I was trying to find the matrix exponential for a matrix that has a determinant of $0$. Here is the matrix:

$$C = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 \\
    -1 & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix} $$

I got only one eigenvalue from the characteristic polynomial, that eigenvalue being $\lambda = 0.$ From there, I got one eigenvector and it was $$\begin{bmatrix}
    -1 \\
    1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

I was trying to begin the process of how I usually find the constants to later write the solution vector, and all I had was:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    0 \\
\end{bmatrix} = c_1\begin{bmatrix}
    -1 \\
    1 \\
\end{bmatrix} $$

I am really confused after this step, and I feel like I cannot calculate the the matrix exponential of $C$ because it has no inverse.

> *What should I do? Is it possible to calculate?*

I tried to go to [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=matrixexp(t+%7B%7B1,1%7D,%7B-1,-1%7D%7D)), and it should be a solution, but I was not sure how they obtained it. Could someone please help me?

Comment: What happens when you just multiply C by itself?

Comment: By the way, the characteristic polynomial is $p(\lambda)=\lambda^2$. This matrix is not diagonalizable, of course.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yeah, that's what I meant. Let me insert a comma.

Comment: Some good answers. The closest thing to diagonal, when that is not possible, is called Jordan Normal Form. I answered with just that aspect.

Answer (score 5):

Note that $C$ is nilpotent:
$$ C^2=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\-1&-1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\-1&-1\end{bmatrix}=0$$
Therefore $e^C$ can be computed directly from the definition:
$$ e^C=I+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{C^k}{k!}=I+C=\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 4):

Alright, you called your matrix $C.$ Once we get the Jordan normal form, call it $J,$ using
$$ A^{-1} C A = J,  $$ so that
$$ A J A^{-1} = C, $$
we get
$$  e^C = e^{A J A^{-1}} = A e^J A^{-1}. $$
Note that AJA was [a platinum selling album by Steely Dan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aja_%28album%29).

In the material below, what matrix is $A$ and what is $J \; ?$ For that matter, what is $e^J,$ which is just a finite sum?

I cannot tell whether you have heard of Jordan Normal Form, here it is. Note how the first matrix is the inverse of the third.

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 1 \\
-1 & -1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$

First and third:
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Note the answer given by @carmichael561 is the same as the one given by [wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=matrixexp(t+%7B%7B1,1%7D,%7B-1,-1%7D%7D))  but using a $tC$ matrix to get

$$e^{tC} = I + tC = \begin{bmatrix}1+t&t\\-t&1-t\end{bmatrix}$$

where $I$ is the unit matrix

$$I := \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$